# Dask - How to call ".compute()" on multiple dataframes

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have two dataframes that are interdependent in my calculation and I would like to get the results on both with one `compute()` call.
The code can be summarized as follows:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe
import dask.distributed
import pandas as pd

df = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(
    pd.DataFrame({
        "group": ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
        "var_1": [0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0],
        "var_2": [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0]}), npartitions=2)

with dask.distributed.Client() as client:
    for i in range(10):
        df_agg = foo(df)
        df = bar(df, df_agg)

print(df.compute())
print(df_agg.compute()) # -> I would like to have only one .compute() call and get the results of both dataframes (df and df_agg)
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

just use dask.compute...
https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.compute.html

```
    print(dask.compute(df, df_agg))
```

Comment: Ok now I feel dumb aha. Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: this one is a secret superpower. it's really helpful to be able to schedule shared tasks like this - we use it all the time for simultaneous ETL & validation, or for all kinds of tasks where you want to read once but do a number of transform & save operations :D